# Issues in implementing Rob-W's CORS anywhere to make post request with authentications work

Tags: reactjs, cors, cors-anywhere

I am making a React application, and very recently, I am trying to call API requests to the Back-end server. The problems emerged when I try to include credentials into the headers of my API requests, when the the browser throws an error that says they cannot fetch it
[The error that occurs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGhcc.png)

Upon closer investigation, I realized that it was a CORS issue (as seen in the preflight request), so I used the demo version of cors-anywhere, and to my surprise it allowed to send the request.
[Instance of cors-anywhere working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJj2B.png)

Although this works, I am fully aware that this cannot last for long, as the demo server is public.

```
import React from "react";
import useAuth from "../../Hooks/useAuth";

export default function UploadJSX(){
    const {auth} = useAuth();
    const token = auth.accessToken;
    
    const uploadPost = async () =>{
        await fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://initiare-website-2603191647bb.herokuapp.com/api/v1/articles`,
            {
              method: "POST",
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                Authorization: "Bearer " + token
              },
              body: JSON.stringify({
                content: "Uploaded via cors-anywhere"
              })
            }
          )
    }
    return(
        <>
            <button onClick={uploadPost}>Upload a post right here</button>
        </>
    )
}
```

I do not know how to start, or what to do regarding this problem. Is there any way I can resolve this without the use of cors-anywhere, like meddling with proxies for example? Either way, as I am purely Front-end, I am not too sure if this is a back-end problem or not, because the APIs called on Postman works just fine. I'm also unsure whether it could be implemented entirely in Front-end.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue not by using cors-anywhere, but by putting " mode: 'cors' " in the fetching object next to the URL. the fetching now works great with authorization. It is kinda sad that I spent 4 days looking for a solution when the fix is literally 1 line of code